# Android Geocoder getFromLocation returns 0 results for valid locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

The code snippet below works from most lat/lon coordinates.
However, passing specific coordinates returns no results.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HappyApp.instance(), Locale.getDefault());
Log.w(TAG, "geocoder object created and is present: " + Geocoder.isPresent());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(32.0923805, 35.165159, 1);
Log.w(TAG, "List size: " + addresses.size());
```

Geocoder.isPresent() returns true.
List size is 0.
The location can be confirmaed by typing Ari'el in Google maps.
Same for Gaza (just Gaza not strip).

My question is it an issue with Android API/Google maps or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Google avoid providing Country and other data where the territory is under controversy dispute like north Cyprus and the Gaza strip.

Whenever we get 0 results, we use the following online service: http://www.geonames.org

Comment: That is weird, because we are trying to use this over South Africa and I am relatively sure that we are not under controversy dispute

Comment: @Peter_File `double upperRightLat = -22.146708;`
      `double lowerLeftLatt = -35.317366;`
      `double upperRightLong = 36.188965;`
      `double lowerLeftLong = 15.095215;`

Answer (score 0):

Google maps geocoder is not available in all regions of the world , period.
If the same app will work for a different region except for a particular one (esp Africa and Middle East), its just because that area isnt really covered by geocoder.

:(

Comment: Now that is just as incorrect, because it geocodes addresses perfectly. It might be that placemarks aren't available in third world countries